# "Ein Knopf ist schwer zu drücken." Wie sagt man das?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

In Englisch steht hier:

> All the buttons work smothly whereas in earlier models the buttons were a bit sticky.

sticky.. "klebrig" passt hier irgendwie nicht.
Wie würde man das auf Deutsch ausdrücken?

Comment: Klebrig passt perfekt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Umgangssprachlich sind die Tasten **hakelig**. 
 Beschreibt wenn die Knöpfe mal besser, mal schlechter funktionieren. Ist meist die beste Übersetzung von "sticky".

Etwas formeller ist **schwergängig**.
Hier fehlt allerdings die zufällige Komponente die in "hakelig" steckt, die Tasten sind in dieser Formulierung immer schwer zu drücken.

Comment: Perfekt, danach habe ich gesucht! :-)

Comment: Alternativ: "die Knöpfe klemmen"

Comment: "Hakelig" wird nicht im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum verwendet. Dem Durchschnitts-Österreich klingt das Wort zu bundesdeutsch. Man würde eher sagen »der Knopf klemmt« oder »der Knopf steckt« (auch »der Knopf steckt fest«), wobei ja die eigentliche Bedeutung durchaus eine andere ist. Aber das englische »sticky« passt sogar besser zu »klemmt« und »steckt« als das deutsche »hakelig«. Aber »schwergängig« ist sicherlich die beste Wahl.

Comment: "hakelig" würde ich eher ganz speziell damit assoziieren, dass eine Drucktaste manchmal nicht wieder "zurückschnappt" (in ihre Ausgangsposition), nachdem kein Druck mehr ausgeübt wird (weil sie sich irgendwie in der Druckposition "verhakt" hat). Das heißt nicht zwangsläufig, dass es schwer sein muss, sie zu drücken, oder dass sie allgemein "schlecht funktioniert" (also z.B. manchmal nicht reagiert).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Prinzipiell hast du recht. Aber eine hakelige Taste kann schon beim Eindrücken einen Widerstand leisten, wenn sie im falschen Winkel gedrückt wird. Der Führungsstift der Taste fährt in einem kleinen Schacht auf und ab und kann sich dort verkanten. Das kann nicht nur bei der Rückstellbewegung, sondern auch beim Eindrücken passieren.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Das stimmt, so eine Taste würde ich ggf. auch als "hakelig" bezeichnen.

Comment: Was Hubert sagt, gilt auch für Bayern. Mir ist das Wort »hakelig« gar nicht bekannt. Ich wüsste spontan kein einzelnes Wort, was ich anstelle von »schwergängig« dort einbrächte … allerdings klemmen oder hängen gerne mal (Druck-)Knöpfe, wenn sie nicht sogar gleich »störrisch« sind ;)

Comment: "Hakelig" ist FALSCH für Knöpfe an Anziehsachen. Es passt nur für Tastaturknöpfe, wenn sie schlecht zurückschnappen.

Comment: @falkb: Deshalb spreche ich in meiner Antwort überwiegend von "Tasten". Der technische Kontext der Frage ist klar, auch wenn OP "Knöpfe" schreibt, v.a. weil i.a. nur Knöpfe = Tasten gedrückt werden. Knöpfe an Kleidung werden selbstverständlich geschlossen, selbst Druckknöpfe. Die anderen Antworten und Kommentare sehen das offenbar ebenso. Umgangssprachlich werden Tasten eben auch als Knöpfe bezeichnet, vor allem, wenn sie rund sind.

Answer (score 4):

Zusätzlich zu [Stephies Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22573/5999) hier zwei weitere Alternativen:

- **eine Taste/ein Knopf ist schwer zu drücken:** Eigentlich spricht nichts gegen genau diese Formulierung, die in der Frage bereits auftauchte. Sie bedeutet ganz direkt, dass man ungewöhnlich viel Kraft aufwenden muss, um eine Taste zu drücken, dass also der physische Widerstand beim Druck unerwünscht hoch ist.
- **eine Taste/ein Knopf lässt sich [nur] schwer drücken:** Das hat dieselbe Bedeutung, aber klingt eine Idee förmlicher und würde eher in einem geschriebenen Dokument auftauchen.

Answer (score 2):

Vorschlag:

> ... bei den älteren Modellen klemmten die Knöpfe etwas.